# Creating/Accessing new database

Tags: authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a new database in SQL Server 2008 R2 on my local machine.

The problem is that for some reason I CAN'T seem to get the it so I can use SQL Server Authentication. I am only able to log in with Windows Authentication.

Would someone describe the steps so that I can access a database that I created with a newly created account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen when you do not install SQL Server under Mixed Mode Authentication. To change this:

1. open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
2. Right click the server
3. click Properties
4. click Security
5. Under "Server Authentication" select "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode"

See the docs for complete details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670(v=sql.105).aspx